# If-Else statement only performing else

Tags: c#, if-statement, steam

I am trying to create a chatbot for steam using SteamKit2. I have a predefined set of messages in a text document that the program can read off of, but I want it to say a specific response when the received message is not on this list. I tried using an if-else statement, but when I message the bot, it only replies with the else response, and not the predefined response.

```
while ((rLine = sReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    string text = rLine.Remove(rLine.IndexOf('|') - 1);  //message | response
    string response = rLine.Remove(0, rLine.IndexOf('|') + 2) ;
    string realText = text.ToLower();

    if (callback.Message.Contains(realText) || callback.Message.Contains(text))
    {
        steamFriends.SendChatMessage(callback.Sender, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, response);
        Console.WriteLine("Someone has messaged me, and I replied with an automated message.");
        sReader.Close();
        return;
    } else {
        steamFriends.SendChatMessage(callback.Sender, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, "I don't know what you mean. Could you maybe write it a bit differently? <3");
        Console.WriteLine("Someone has messaged me, and it wasn't on my auto-response list: {0}",callback.Message);
        sReader.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's because you're (presumably) looping through each line in the file. However, you're immediately returning if it's not found. Your `else` block should be outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: To clarify, unless the text you're entering is on the first line of the file, the `else` will always execute. The `else` block should only execute if **none** of the lines in your text file match the callback message.

Comment: How would I do that? When I move the else block out of the while loop, I get an error. Also, I am looping through each line in the file. Thanks

Comment: Can you give me more information not just 'an error'? In any case, see my answer, it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Re-write it to be this:

```
while ((rLine = sReader.ReadLine()) != null) {
    string text = rLine.Remove(rLine.IndexOf('|') - 1);  //message | response
    string response = rLine.Remove(0, rLine.IndexOf('|') + 2) ;
    string realText = text.ToLower();

    if (callback.Message.Contains(realText) || callback.Message.Contains(text))
    {
        steamFriends.SendChatMessage(callback.Sender, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, response);
        Console.WriteLine("Someone has messaged me, and I replied with an automated message.");
        sReader.Close();
        return;
    }
}

steamFriends.SendChatMessage(callback.Sender, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, "I don't know what you mean. Could you maybe write it a bit differently? <3");
Console.WriteLine("Someone has messaged me, and it    wasn't on my auto-response list: {0}",callback.Message);
sReader.Close();
return;
```

Comment: It crashes whenever you type something not on the list. When I put else around it, showed an error: "} expected" at the end of the while loop.